# Flutter | Local Notification : ZonedSchedule only firing once

Tags: flutter, localnotification, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to setup `Local Notifications` in Flutter app and need the notifications to fire once daily and the notification text to be read from `SQLite`.

For testing I am trying to have to run these every 2 minutes to see if it picks up the data from `SQLite` correctly, however it seems to run only once...

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      notificationID,
      "Dynamic Data",
    await getData(),
       _nextInstanceOfTime(initialHour,initialMin),// have defined an initial hr and min to start the notification
       const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails('1', 'test', 'test')),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
      UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time
  );

tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfTime(int hour, int minutes) {
Duration offsetTime= DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset;
tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate;
tz.TZDateTime currentTime;

if (offsetTime.isNegative) {
  scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime.local(DateTime.now().year,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day,hour,minutes)
      .add(offsetTime);
  currentTime = tz.TZDateTime.local(DateTime.now().year,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day,DateTime.now().hour,DateTime.now().minute)
      .add(offsetTime);
}
else {
  scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime.local(DateTime.now().year,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day,hour,minutes)
      .subtract(offsetTime);
  currentTime = tz.TZDateTime.local(DateTime.now().year,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day,DateTime.now().hour,DateTime.now().minute)
      .subtract(offsetTime);
}


if (scheduledDate.isBefore(currentTime)) {
  scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
}
scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(minutes: 2));//->>> WANTING TO TEST FIRING IT EVERY 2 MINS
print("next notification:$scheduledDate"); // ->> THIS PRINTS ONLY ONCE
return scheduledDate;
```

}

getData() gets the random String from SQlite

The print("next notification:$scheduledDate") prints only once and not after every 2 minutes as I need.

Please help !!

Thanks